# Understanding how PCB CAD designs affect the final product

Tags: kicad, cad, fritzing

I'm looking to design my first printed circuit board and having trouble understanding PCB CAD systems conceptually. I've started on schematics with EasyEDA, KiCAD, and Fritzing without finishing, as there is a lot of detail and it's rather unclear what's important. In software terms, I don't know which fields are *code* with an actual effect on the product, and what stuff is *comments* that's just there for human communication, or to make a drawing look pretty?

There are large libraries of user-contributed part definitions and I'm reluctant to use them because I don't know how to evaluate them. What does quality look like and what's going to screw me up if it's wrong?

I have hand-wired a couple of projects by cutting FR4 and drilling a lot of holes in a couple of boards with less precision than I'd like. I have a simple model of how an unsophisticated through-hole based board design should work, where if the holes are in the right places and there is connectivity between the right holes, this is what actually matters? But there seems to be a lot of other stuff involved in drawing schematics and maybe simulation, design rules and so on, and I don't know how much of it is important.

I'd appreciate any explanations or references to conceptual introductions you might know about.

Comment: I honestly would not fret too much about it since this is just for personal use so just have at it and ignore the stuff you don't recognize. But think critically about what is logically needed and if you think of something you need, then go looking for it. No point getting bogged down in features you don't need (and there are a lot. If you don't recognize it, move on). In the end, you will just end up with a Gerber which is what really matters. You should open up in some Gerber viewing software (I use DFM Now, it's free) and look at your PCB and see if everything is as it should be.

Comment: Welcome! But a bit of a downer upfront: this is a bit too broad for a question here, I'm afraid. You're basically asking us for a complete intro to PCB design! Think about this: While you're right in many cases, connectivity is what counts, this doesn't really apply in all cases. Think about this: if you're, say, connecting an LED to some IC, the thickness, length and position of the PCB trace on your self-manufactured PCB won't matter – as long as it was thick enough to etch/mill, it'll be thick enough to carry the LED current. Now imagine you're building a motor controller – suddenly you

Comment: want to carry dozens of ampere, and your trace width becomes critical (or else you'll be building an involuntary fuse). The width, and position to other traces might not be critical for an LED, but imagine you're building a PCB that connects to a 5.8 GHz antenna, for WiFi purposes. Now, your trace needs to be very particularly shaped so that it becomes a waveguide, instead of some leaky antenna/absorber. Your 48 MHz microcontroller needs decoupling caps – with less than microhenries in trace inductance, so placement of these becomes critical. Crosstalk, heat management, … the list is long.

Comment: You are asking questions that cannot be realistically addressed here in the question and answer format of this site. Basically what you are asking is for the knowledge that experienced electrical engineers have garnered through years of making designs, schematics and PCB layouts. This site is aimed squarely at specific design questions that you may have rather than providing a huge core dump of "how to be a successful engineer". Please try to edit your question down to one specific design related thing and you may actually be able to get some help with that.

Comment: So, I really think it's fair to say: "Things depend so much that you'll barely find any engineer who knows how to design optimal PCBs for *every* application." If you can restrict yourself to a specific type of application/circuitry, you might be able to narrow down your question to something someone can answer – without citing a book in completeness :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller As broad as the OP's question is, I think you read it as an even broader one. I think the OP is just wondering about usage of the software itself and all the extra features in it. Not PCB design per se, but using PCB design software. For example, the first time you try and make an footprint, there's dozens of different layers and you have no idea which ones are actually necessary. Or you run into all the default DRC design rules in the layout software. Or all the annotation or  hierarchy options in schematic software.

Comment: @DKNguyen - Specific questions as you just posed are the type of thing that the OP should be asking here. Things they do not understand as they engage and find minor road blocks to moving ahead. This is the best way to learn while walking baby steps on the ground instead of taking it all at once by diving off the 30 meter high board.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I think the OP is just being bombarded by so much it all looks the same like a wall of text. It's hard to pick out what part to ask about because you can't even recognize distinct parts and things are coming at you from all directions. My advice: Ignore anything you don't recognize and if you think something is needed go looking for it. As you learn more you will recognize more and realize you need new things. And the Gerber is king.

Comment: The main thing the schematic does is document the net connectivity which includes package information for each part) and allow accurate generation of a BOM for purchasing. For a schematic to be correct, all manufacturers and part numbers must be correct, the netlist must be correct, and the package information must be correct so that the layout tool will generate correct footprints for all components.

Comment: To clarify a bit: I want to order a printed circuit board to be made. This is the reason I need to learn to use CAD software, unless there is something else recommended that I should look into. I'm a hobbyist working alone and I will be soldering components to the board myself. When using KiCAD or similar software, what's going to affect my order to the board-making service?

Comment: @BrianSlesinsky - I don't want to post a link only answer, but I highly recommend John's Basement's KiCAD tutorials on YouTube (playlist: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3by7evD3F51fKkyrUbH-PCdwPCWc9F8a). He does a simple PCB from scratch and has in made, so it should be right up your street.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a pcb you need to have the information required for every layer the board house needs (copper, soldermask, silk and the board outline). These layers are typically sent via so called gerber files.

The PCB Layout software uses footprints that define the interface with every component (Pads in a footprint define the places where the leads are soldered to, graphics on technical layers help for documentation like silk screen)

To define which pads need to be connected with traces (or other means) you use the connectivity information that you get from the schematic.

The schematic is build up from symbols that are the abstract view of the function of every component (The schematic is then the abstract view of the systems intended function)
Symbols define pins that are mapped to footprint pads (via the pin/pad numbers and the footprint field of the symbol). You define the connectivity information by using wires that are used to connect pins together. (or you can also use labels or power symbols)

---

I have made a KiCad version 5.1 specific tutorial that shows the minimum requirement for getting a finished board designed. https://forum.kicad.info/t/tutorial-introduction-to-pcb-design-with-kicad-version-5-1-getting-started/20600/

There are other similar tutorials out there. Some also as videos if you prefer that style. But make sure they really use the correct version of KiCad as the interface is quite different between different major versions.